# ASP.NET detect return File in view to hide image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

How do I detect when ASP.NET returns a file?  Recently I decided to add the following code to display a loading gif every time a button is pressed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.btn').click(function() {
    jQuery(".loader").show();
});
```

I have a loader div, and I have css that displays the gif.  That all works perfectly.  When the button runs controller code that returns RedirectToAction it works perfectly.  The problem is when the controller returns a File().  When RedirectToAction fires the page reloads, and the loading gif is gone.  When a file is returned, the loading gif stays on the screen.

Does anyone know how to hide this gif when a file is returned, or a better way to handle the loading gif?  I'm fine changing the structure, so I'll take any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `UpdatePanel` and `UpdateProgress` controls.

[UpdatePanel on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)

[UpdateProgress on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx)

#### To Summarize

The UpdatePanel contains your page controls and the UpdateProgress is where your loading gif will go.

Consider the following example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="updExample">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" id="btnSubmit" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="uppExample">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="progress-loader">
            <img src="/App_Themes/Default/Images/loader.gif" />
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

This should display the loader gif when you click on the button associated with the form on your page.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify.  I'm currently using MVC.  Can I just change the syntax and do the same thing?